# How do I ignore a Typescript error in a Javascript file (whilst I have `allowJs` set in my tsConfig)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, compiler-errors

I have a handful of .js files in my Typescript project that looks something like this:

```js
// do some things

return JSON.stringify(
  {
    ok: true,
    // blah blah blah
  },
  null,
  2
);
```

However, when I run `tsc` to type check my project, which has `allowJs` enabled, I receive this error:

```
error TS1108: A 'return' statement can only be used within a function body.
  return JSON.stringify(
  ~~~~~~
```

I'm confident in why I'm doing this (the code gets handed over to [Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/javascript/udf-javascript-introduction.html)) and would like to ignore this error.

Normally I would include a `// @ts-expect-error` directly above the offending return statement, however, this doesn't work. Apparently, because it's a javascript file, not a typescript file: if I change the file extension to .ts, the `// @ts-expect-error` comment behaves as expected and suppresses the error, however, it causes a bunch of other errors, as should be expected.

Comment: How is this file involved in the transpilation process? Why do you use the transpiler on files that aren't imported by a TypeScript file?

Comment: `//@ts-nocheck` at the top of your file would solve it temporarily

Comment: @jabaa there are a handful of files that during deployment, are read in (`fs.readFileSync`) and then handed over directly to snowflake which uses them for a UDF

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: What I mean is that this file is not involved in the transpilation process. It's simply type-checked by tsc.